# Unsigned Integers to Floating Point in Java

Tags: java, unsigned

How can I convert an unsigned int or long represented as the signed Java equivalents to float or double in Java? I found some hints in the Google Guava libraries ([Link](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLong.html#line.199)), but I do not understand the reasoning behind the implementation. Here is the code fragment that converts an unsigned long stored in `value` to float:

```
198  @Override
199  public float floatValue() {
200    @SuppressWarnings("cast")
201    float fValue = (float) (value & UNSIGNED_MASK);
202    if (value < 0) {
203      fValue += 0x1.0p63f;
204    }
205    return fValue;
206  }
```

As far as I understand, the first check is necessary to check that the value is not negative since the `UNSIGNED_MASK` is `Long.MAX_VALUE`. In this case, the conversion matches the Java semantics of long to float conversion. But why is a constant added, if the value is negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to treat to original long `value` as if it's unsigned, if the signed value is negative, you have to add 2^63 to account for the sign bit.

If the original `value` is already positive, you don't have to add anything, since the sign bit is 0, so only the value of the bottom 63 bits should be considered.

For example, take `1111...111111` (64 1 bits).

The signed value of this long number is `-1`.

However, the unsigned value is `2^63+2^62+...+2^1+2^0`.

`(float) (value & UNSIGNED_MASK)` will give you the float value of `2^62+2^61+...+2^1+2^0`.

Therefore you have to add `2^63`.